# how to get the id of an object in an array angular

Tags: angular

I have a component that show a list of book

```
<div class="col-lag-12">


  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let book of books; let i = index">
      <div class="avatar_book">
        <img src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + book.image }}" alt="">
      </div>
    <h4>
      <a [routerLink]="['/inicio']">
        {{book.title}}
      </a>
    </h4>
    <p>{{book.description}}</p>
    <p>{{book.author}}</p>
    <p>{{book.stock}}</p>
    <p>{{book.price}} $</p>
    <a [routerLink]="['/updatebook', i]" (click)="getId()" class="btn btn-primary float-right">update</a>

   </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="pagination">
   <li class="page-item">
     <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="['/pruebabook', prev_page]">&laquo;</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page-item" *ngFor="let num of number_pages">
      <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="['/pruebabook', num]" href="">{{ num }}</a>
   </li>

   <li class="page-item">
     <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="['/pruebabook', next_page]">&raquo;</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

JS

```
export class PruebabookComponent implements OnInit {

  public identity;
  public token;
  public books: Book[];
  public totalPages;
  public page;
  public next_page;
  public prev_page;
  public number_pages;
  public url: string;
  public bookId;
  public book: Book;
  public _id;
  @ViewChild(UpdatebookComponent) updateBook: UpdatebookComponent;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private userservice: UserService,
    private bookservice: BookService
  ) {
     this.url = global.url;
     this.book = new Book('', '', '', '', 1, '');

}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params=>{
      let page:number = +params.get('page');
      console.log(page);
      if (!page) {
        page = 1;
      }
      this.getBooks(page);
    })
  }


 getId()
 {
   // recoger id del libro
   this.bookId = this.books.title;
   console.log(this.bookId);

 }
```

I have an array of books but I can't get the _id of the book when I click on update button

```
0: {_id: "5f2629a958a735467cfca6bb", date: "2020-08-02T02:49:13.641Z", title: "lkjlkj", description: "jlkjlkj", author: "jlkjlkj", …}
```

I get the id of the element of the array with `<a [routerLink]="['/updatebook', i]"`

But how to get the _id of the object in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your li that you are looping with `ngFor`, I am sure you can get your id by book._id, right? So in your `getId(book._id)` function pass `book._id` and console log it, you will get that. Check getId function below. And even you can pass it anywhere you like then. make sure you are receiving it with some param in ts file as well

`getId(x) { console.log(x); }`

Your HTML

```
 <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let book of books; let i = index">
  <div class="avatar_book">
    <img src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + book.image }}" alt="">
  </div>
<h4>
  <a [routerLink]="['/inicio']">
    {{book.title}}
  </a>
</h4>
<p>{{book.description}}</p>
<p>{{book.author}}</p>
<p>{{book.stock}}</p>
<p>{{book.price}} $</p>
<a [routerLink]="['/updatebook', i]" (click)="getId(book._id)" class="btn btn-primary float-right">update</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// pass Book id on click update book click event

<a [routerLink]="['/updatebook', i]" (click)="getId(book._id)" class="btn btn-primary float-right">update</a>

// Get Book Id here
getId (bookId) {
   console.log(bookId); // 5f2629a958a735467cfca6bb
   this.bookId = bookId;
   
}
```